# Sort sub array minimaly

Tags: algorithm

This is an interview question.
Given an array of integers, write a method to find indices m and n such that if you sorted elements m through n, the entire array would be sorted. Minimize n-m. i.e. find smallest sequence.

Answer (score 6):

#### Observation

The integers before m should be ascending and smaller than (or equal to) any integers after.

#### Algorithm

1. Start from the first element, and stop upon first decreasing. (sub array SA)
2. Find minimum after. (MIN)
3. The start point is just after the maximum integer in SA that is smaller than (or equal to) MIN. (m is found)

#### Complexity

O(N)

---

Do similar for n.

Answer (score 4):

You need to keep track of four things:

1. End of sorted region at the beginning
2. Start of sorted region at the end
3. Minimum number after the beginning region
4. Maximum number before the end region

Start by figuring out a preliminary value for 1 and 2, by scanning the array from the start and from the end until you find a misplaced value.

Then you scan everything after your preliminary 1, to find the minimum number. This is your 3. Find 4 in the same way.

Now you backtrack trough the start region of the array until you find the place where the minimum value should be. This is the exact answer to 1 and also your `m`.

Find `n` in the same way by backtracking through the end region to find where the maximum number should be.